# javascript object literal - nested functions and the "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, object, this, literals

In the example below, when `functionA()` is invoked, the `this` keyword refers to the containing object, so I can access its properties (e.g. `theValue`)

**My question:** How do I refer to properties of `myObj` from within the *nested* `functionB()`?

```
var myObj = {
    theValue: "The rain in Spain", 
    functionA: function() {
        alert(this.theValue);
    },
    moreFunctions: {
        functionB: function() {
            alert(????.theValue);
        }
    }
}

myObj.functionA(); 
myObj.moreFunctions.functionB();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Immediate invocation to the rescue!

```
var myObj = (function () {
    var that = {
        theValue: "The rain in Spain", 
        functionA: function() {
            alert(this.theValue); // or that.theValue, both work here
        },
        moreFunctions: {
            functionB: function() {
                alert(that.theValue);
            }
        }
    };
    return that;
}()); // <-- immediate invocation !!
```

You can decompose it even further:

```
var myObj = (function () {
    function functionA() {
        alert(that.theValue);
    }
    function functionB() {
        alert(that.theValue);
    }
    var that = {
        theValue: "The rain in Spain", 
        functionA: functionA,
        moreFunctions: {
            functionB: functionB
        }
    }
    return that;
}());
```

If you're familiar with OOP, you can use this to make **private** variables.

Comment: I'm confused about which answer to accept.  elclanrs' suggestion (`alert(myObj.theValue);`) works (with no refactoring required), but Frits' solution (and a bit more research) has provided me with information on closures, immediate invocation, & how this can be used to make private variables, so I'm accepting this answer on that basis.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use `myObj`:

```
alert(myObj.theValue);
```

Check demo http://jsbin.com/izugon/2/edit

Answer (score 3):

A common practice is to define a "self" variable and use that rather than the this keyword. This helps when you wish to add scope or create a class.

```
var myObj = new function(){
    var self = this;
    this.theValue = "The rain in Spain";
    this.functionA = function() {
        alert(self.theValue);
    },
    this.moreFunctions = {
        functionB: function() {
            alert(self.theValue);
        }
    }
   }();

   myObj.functionA();
   myObj.moreFunctions.functionB();
```

Another possibility is to use the ECMA5 Function.prototype.bind method. To put it simply, you can bind a method's *this* keyword. [Follow the link or use a search engine for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). If you use this method, beware that it is not compatible with older browsers, but the provided link shows an alternate implementation you may use to implement the *.bind* method in older browsers.

```
var myObj = new function(){
    this.theValue = "The rain in Spain";
    this.functionA = function() {
        alert(this.theValue);
    }.bind(this);
    this.moreFunctions = {
        functionB: function() {
            alert(this.theValue);
        }.bind(this)
    };
}();

myObj.functionA();
myObj.moreFunctions.functionB();
```

Comment: Nop: http://jsbin.com/ofehap/1/edit, `this` in there is `window`. `this` applies _inside_ functions, and the context depends on _how you call_ that function.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. After your edit it'll work but you've just changed the data structure. Plus the option with `bind` will not work because `this` is still `window`.

Comment: You are right, when I originally read this I had a function in mind, rather than a simple clean JSON structure. I fixed the code to make it work as I originally intended, but I do not recommend it as the answer if you want to keep it clean JSON. However, the scoping does make it more attractive.

Comment: I'll remove the down vote for the effort, but you've said it already, this is not a great answer. For the scoping you can just use a module pattern approach like the answer by @FritsvanCampen.