# Seeing error when I map over two json objects --> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stars' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to map over two json objects, but am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stars' of undefined
```

To give some context, I'm building a reviews system (where you can rate a meal 1-5 stars). I have a stars.json and comments.json file and want to keep both separate instead of combine the two. To render both the users comment and star rating, I want to map over each json object, but thats when I get the error above. I'm passing in the right props too...

```
<ReviewList comments={this.state.comments} stars={this.state.stars} />
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my code:

```
var ReviewList = React.createClass({
render: function(){
    var commentNodes = this.props.comments.map(function(comment){
        this.props.stars.map(function(star){
            return (
                <Comment comment={comment} star={star} />
            );  
        })
    });

    return (
        <div className="reviewList">
            {commentNodes}
        </div>
    );
}
});

var Comment = React.createClass({
render: function(){
    return (
        <div className="comment">
                {this.props.comment.comment}
                ({this.props.star.star})
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` inside `render()` refers to ReviewList object. But `this` inside comments.map refers to each object in comments and not the whole object (ReviewList).

One way is to save the reference of `this` outside map so that it can be used inside. Something like this

```
var that = this;
var commentNodes = this.props.comments.map(function(comment){
    return that.props.stars.map(function(star){
        return (
            <Comment comment={comment} star={star} />
        );  
    });
});
```

Other way to do is by using [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) map so that `this` outside map is available inside. Something like this

```
var commentNodes = this.props.comments.map(function(comment){
    return this.props.stars.map(function(star){
        return (
            <Comment comment={comment} star={star} />
        );  
    })
}.bind(this)); // <---- bind will make this outside map available inside
```

Read more about how this works in nested functions. Here is one of the references

[javascript object literal - nested functions and the "this" keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098805/javascript-object-literal-nested-functions-and-the-this-keyword)

Comment: oh awesome. I'm getting no errors now, but it's still not quite working completely. i should expect to see a list of reviews (aka commentNodes) but they are not rendering at all. I'm wondering if it has to do with getInitialState but that looks alright on my end too.

Comment: Btw, I forgot to mention that you have to return the inner map too. I updated the answer. Also, I created a sample here http://jsbin.com/goboso/edit?html,output See if you're doing something like that.